# Aligning all the app to the right

Tags: android, xml

I've searched how can I align the app to the right side and the text to be written from right to left. 
The only thing I've found and succeeded to do is to make the text be written from right to left by adding `android:gravity="right"`
 in the EditText and the Button, but still their sort in the line if from the left to the right.
The activity_main.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/text_message"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_weight="1.0"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/text_message" />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/send_button"
     android:onClick="ButtonClicked" />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/delete_button"
     android:onClick="DeleteClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I meant in "the sort is from the left to the right" is that the EditText is written before the "Send" button, and the "Send" button id written before the "Delete" button - so what's shown is
 "[***_*___***x*] [Send][Delete]" and not "[Delete][Send][***_*____**]", as I would want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead of `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` and give your buttons some ids using

```
android:id="@+id/your_button_id
```

and then use the tags `android:layout_toRightOf` and `android:layout_toLeftOf`. In your case, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button android:id="@+id/delete_button" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/delete_button"
 android:onClick="DeleteClicked" />

<Button android:id="@+id/send_button" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/delete_button"
 android:text="@string/send_button"
 android:onClick="ButtonClicked" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/text_message"
 android:layout_weight="1.0"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/send_button"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="@string/text_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Might be an options, but as a lazy person and programmer I always try to find the easiest and shortest way, isn't there an option like this in this case?

Comment: @RoniCopul Have you tried to define `deleteButton` first, `sendButton` second and third your `editext` in your xml? I believe the definition order does matter in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I'm sure it will work but it's not really comfortable to define everything upside down...

Comment: I think I'll just do the toRightOf ;) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Stop being a lazy programmer. Just makes everything harder for you in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:layout_gravity
```

You could also just use a RelativeLayout add

```
android:align_ParentRight="true"
```

Comment: One of the places I've read from told that it wouldn't help, but I'll try.. Am I supposed to add this to the <LinearLayout> ?

Comment: You can for sure move everything to a RelativeLayout and then set align_ParentRight. That will work for sure.

Comment: I was under the impression that yes, align_ParentRight only worked in a RelativeLayout. android:layout_gravity attributed to the <LinearLayout> should work though...

Comment: @FrankSposaro What will get the align_ParentRight property?

Comment: @Addison yes, I thought layout_gravity should work in a LinearLayout too. Perhaps it needs to be in the parent and not the children. IDK what roni tested.

Comment: @FrankSposaro It should work in the parent, I've done it a couple times recently in the app I'm working on. However, I think Roni didn't mean his question exactly as he asked it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:gravity="right"
```

to

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Comment: If you'll check out the comments you'll see that I said it doesn't work

Comment: Oh okay I just checked out your XML, your title threw me off. Sorry about that.